# Deal with ng-show with Jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug

I'm trying to show and hide dynamically some `<div>` written with Jade. It seemed quite easy as [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_htmldom.asp) says but I'm getting stuck now to make it works.

I'm going to make up a web application with a sidebar. For each index of it I want to show and hide pieces of html, given within `<div>` tags, depending on which one the user will click on.

The following scratch of code shows four `<div>` tag (test1, test2, test3, test4) which I want to show or hide depending on some variables (test1Visible, test2Visible, test3Visible, test4Visible) filled in my controller.

```
  body(ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl')
  //...
  #test1(ng-show='test1Visible')
    include test.jade

  #test2(ng-show='test2Visible')
    include test.jade

  #test3(ng-show='test3Visible')
    include test.jade

  #test4(ng-show='test4Visible')
    include test.jade
  //...
```

By default none of these divs is shown and I'm wondering if the strategy of using `test#Visible` variables is the right way.

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with it. If you want at least one shown all the time just write that into the logic for whatever action causes them to show/hide. But if these are more like different pages of your application I would look into using ui-router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

Simply didn't figured that `ng-controller='myCtrl'` had been declared more than one time. That caused my problem.